# Storing photos on server when using Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api, photo

Can we store the photos we pull to our site using Google Places - we essentially pull the info about a hotel, for example, including the picture made available through the Google Places API, and then allow users on our site to view the info, including the pictures - can these pictures that were pulled remain on our server?

Thanks

Comment: More suited to the law.stackexchange.com site?  Sounds like a copyright and licensing issue to me, rather than a technical problem.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Didn’t know that existed